# getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not string while inserting data into postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to push data into the postgres using list comprehension and morgify but i' getting the error.

actually, the sort is the dictionary in the following format:

```
sort = {'forecast': [{'name': some_value, 'search_volume': some_int_value, 
'competition': some_float_value}]}

data_text = ','.join(c.mogrify(
    "(%(k)s,%(l['name'])s,l['search_volume'],l['competition'])",
    l) for l in [v for k,v in sort.items()])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lonewolf/PycharmProjects/seo_keyword_research_tools-master/keyword_expansion_tool.py", line 137, in get_lsi
    expand(current_word)
  File "/Users/lonewolf/PycharmProjects/seo_keyword_research_tools-master/keyword_expansion_tool.py", line 121, in expand
    sorted_data = write_to_file(current_results, current_word)
  File "/Users/lonewolf/PycharmProjects/seo_keyword_research_tools-master/keyword_expansion_tool.py", line 107, in write_to_file
    l) for l in [v for k,v in sort.items()])
  File "/Users/lonewolf/PycharmProjects/seo_keyword_research_tools-master/keyword_expansion_tool.py", line 107, in <genexpr>
    l) for l in [v for k,v in sort.items()])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: It would appear as though `l` is a list, not a dictionary.

Comment: Please show the traceback. There's a lot going on in that list comp and we can't see any of it. If the code is read by others, do you think the intention is clear?

Comment: but [v for k,v in sort.items()] should give me list of dictionary!! I'm iterating this with l so each l instead should be a dictionary right?

Comment: Please stop with the "!!". I can't help but read it as you shouting at us, which I don't think you intend

Comment: that came out of suggestion i indented to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change syntax to:

```
c.mogrify(
    "(%(k)s,%(name)s,%(search_volume)s,%(competition)s",
    {'k': k, 'name': l['name'],
     'search_volume': l['search_volume'],
     'competition': l['competition'] })
```

by passing required values, not an object.

Please **note**, that this doesn't seem to be a valid SQL expression which is expected as the first argument of **psycopg**'s [mogrify](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify)